# How to override leftbarbutton item with backbutton

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, back-button, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller

My storyboard flow provides two entry points with diffrent view controllers(backed by navigation controller)

first is

-> NC -> A -> B -> C

second is

-> NC -> B -> C

It's all being presented as a modal form sheet on iPad.
RootVCs (A and B) have close left bar button item defined in storyboard and hooked up to method which dismisses modal.

The question is:
Is there any way to override leftbarrbuttonitem with backbutton in B vc? Have a look first flow case when navigationcontroller pushes from A to B.

In either flow I would have close button only in rootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I came up with is implementing following code in viewDidLoad of B vc:

```
if (![self.navigationController.viewControllers.firstObject isEqual:self]) {
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below code,

You can customize your own back button.,

It may help you.. :)

```
[self setBackbtn];   //from didload

-(void)setBackbtn
{
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_back.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(-20, 0, 50, 50);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

//    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
    [customBarItem release];


}

- (void)back {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
   //You can customize here what you want
}
```

Comment: I know, but I want to avoid such solution. It makes code ugly and less dependent on storyboard.

It appears that leftBarButtonItem overriders backButton - so the simplest solution is to remove it when needed.